# Where to invoke VIPS_INIT in a C shared library

Tags: c, shared-libraries, vips

I am working on a C shared library that would contain one function that receives a filename, and returns a pointer to the C-array representation of the image.

I read `VIPS_INIT` needs to be set in the beginning of the program, with `argv[0]` as its argument. However, since this is a shared library, I'm not sure where exactly do I need to place this.

Comment: I see. I'll do just that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

libvips uses `argv[0]` to help discover message catalogues if its been relocated. If you don't need a relocatable package, you can just pass `""` and it'll be fine.

Other notes: be careful not to init from more than one thread at the same time, and make sure init finishes before you try any processing.

Comment: I added a note to the docs for this. Thanks! https://github.com/libvips/libvips/commit/81861baee967380dd1e45fe863f57b1c960fcea8